# Need help on basic programming for resonance audio / GVR plugins with Fmod and Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, fmod, resonance-audio

I'm a sound designer working on VR for mobile phone; prototyping on Galaxy S8. 
We use Unity and Fmod, thus GVR plugins ( formerly resonance-audio ). 
It is known that GVR bypass group busses in Fmod for a more precise control on spatialisation for each sources.

Now i have a problem as i'm definitely not a dev so my coding skills are not that great.

I simply want to automate the volume of certain Fmod events, make them fade out on like 10/15 seconds at the end of a scene. Thus i feel like i need automation either on GVR Source Gain from each track, OR the master volume of each event. 
I added a parameter in Fmod, so by coding in Unity i want to tell fmod to smoothly go from a value to another thus fading out the volume.

Issue : the parameter appears in the inspector in Unity, but can't have access to it / can't control it.
I can tick the box of the said parameter, but it automatically untick as soon as i start the scene, and i don't know what to type to control the value.

I have some devs in the team with me that will help, but we're kind in a rush thus im trying to find solutions myself.

TLDR : how to simply automate parameter values of GVR plugins or Fmod event master bus ( not session master bus ) by coding in Unity ? Considering GVR / Resonance-audio bypass groupbusses.

If anyone had the same kind of issue or know how to sort it out... i'll be more than grateful.

regards,

Guillaume

Comment: Can you provide the source code for the exact parameter you are trying to automate?

Comment: Found the solution in the documentation. Apparently i found it days before my post but because i don't code that much i did not realise it before  >< 
A simple but sneaky setVolume something on the event. Solved this with a dev from my team fortunately !